# Array of Values in Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary initialized:

```
var itemsSections = Dictionary<String, [Item?]>()
```

The key of the dictionary should be the Type of an shopping item ("Animal, Baby, Drinks, Beauty, ...) and the value can be an array of Items.

My item class is something like:

```
Class Item :
    public var created: NSCreatedDate?
    public var details: String?
    public var title: String?
    public var unity: float?
    public var quantity: int?
    public var type : String?
```

When I initialize the dictionary, I don't know how many types would be filled, and how many items can be in each array.

When I am adding the  pair, I am getting an error in:

```
//populate the sections

for (item) in self.items
{
    let typeName = (item.type)!

    //itemsSections[typeName]?.append(item) -> this compiles, but the dictionary remain with nothing 

    //itemsSections[typeName]!.append(item) this won't compile,

    //itemsSections[typeName] = [item] -> this works, but if i have one type that is in more than one item, it only shows 1.
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should clean up your data structure first. an Item has an optional title, and quantity? What?!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for (item) in self.items
{
    let typeName = (item.type)!

    var value = itemSections[typeName] ?? []
    value.append(item)
    itemSections[typeName] = value
}
```

`Array` is struct.
The value retrieved by `itemSections[typeName]` is copied one, not the actual data in `itemSections`.You can't append an item to `itemSections`'s data directly. You must append it to the copied array and update `itemSections` with it again.

Additionally the retrieved value would be `nil` when `itemSections` had no data for `typeName`. In this case, the initial empty array is needed. That's the reason of `?? []`

Comment: Can you please explain your reasoning?

Comment: @VascoGomes I updated my answer with an explanation.